# Why can't a top level class be static in Java?

Tags: java, class, static

Can't find a satisfactory answer anywhere.

Comment: Without knowing what answers you found, you're probably just going to get more unsatisfactory answers.

Comment: @BoltClock.. well i found these answers which just asked the reason for such a class but not the reason why they can't be static http://www.coderanch.com/t/515963/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Class-cannot-protected-or-static... and  http://www.coderanch.com/t/523014/java/java/Why-Class-cannot-declared-as.. and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: What does it mean for a nested class to be static? How would that apply to a top-level class?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

All top-level classes are, by definition, static.

What the `static` boils down to is that an instance of the class can stand on its own. Or, the other way around: a non-static inner class (= instance inner class) cannot exist without an instance of the outer class. Since a top-level class does not have an outer class, it can't be anything but `static`.

Because *all* top-level classes are static, having the `static` keyword in a top-level class definition is pointless.

Some code to play around with:

```
public class Foo {

    public class Bar {
         // Non-static innner class
    }

    public static class Baz {
         // Static inner class
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo(); // this is ok
        new Foo.Baz(); // this is ok
        new Foo.Bar(); // does not compile!

        Foo f = new Foo();
        Foo.Bar bar = f.new Bar(); //this works, but don't do this
    }
}
```

I put the "but don't do this" in there because it's *really* ugly code design. Instance inner classes should not be visible outside the outer class. They should only be used from within the outer class.

Comment: @barend.. they why compiler complains when i add static keyword

Comment: The keyword has no value, so they left it out. I think this is a design choice about readability. You have the same thing with the `public` keyword when you define a method on an `interface` (it's just as pointless), but in that case they left it in.

Comment: +1: nested `enum` are effectively `static` and `final` but you can't use either.

Comment: @Peter You can use `static` in fact.

Comment: @Barend can you actually prove that or provide some ref about "All top-level classes are, by definition, static."? I am trying to search online but couldnt' find anything about it. for the interface is implicit public so you can either declare it or not and that doesn't change anything, at least the compiler doesn't complain but for top level class you can't declare static which mean it is not implicitly static! so what make you think they are? thanks.

Comment: @Jaxox I have no refs to give you. What makes me think the above is summarized in the second paragraph. Without an outer class to give object scope/context, a top level class can only ever live in the static (or "global" or whatever you want to call it) scope/context.

Comment: This is quite unsatisfying answer since, (a) no official docs/ source code reference. (b) if `static` is pointless then adding it shouldn't be a problem like adding `public` in interface signatures.

Comment: @Barend if it is as you say and top-level classes are static, can we say that top-level class save in stack area like static fields and methods?

Comment: "By definition" is wrong; the JLS does not give any overall definition of what the word "static" means, and the only things described as being static in the JLS are static fields, static methods, static member type declarations and static initializers. The only top-level declarations described using the word "static" are single-static-import declarations and static-import-on-demand declarations, but in those cases "static" refers to the names imported, not the import declarations themselves. So there is no definition in the JLS which says or implies what you claim is "by definition".

Comment: Being “pointless” is not a valid explanation. A nested `interface` or `enum` type is truly always `static`, still, nothing forbids you to add the redundant “pointless” `static` modifier.

Comment: Top-level classes are not static. You can create instances of them, because they have default constructors. If the class has only static fields and methods, this will only consume memory, and thus "pointless", but nothing prevents you doing it.

Answer (score 13):

Simply put, a top-level type declaration cannot be static, because the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) (JLS) doesn't say that it can be. The JLS [says this explicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1) about the `static` keyword as a modifier of top-level classes:

> The modifier `static` pertains only to member classes (§8.5.1), not to top level or local or anonymous classes.

However, the accepted answer - which has many upvotes - says that this is because top-level classes are implicitly static "by definition", so the `static` modifier would be unnecessary. That is wrong.

The word "static" appears in the JLS in quite a few places, but never to refer to top-level type declarations. Here is an exhaustive list of things that *can* be "static":

- [Static fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1), also called static variables, including [static constant variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9)
- [Static methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2)
- [Static member type declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1)
- "Static members", which are the three constructs above
- [Static initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)
- [Single-static-import declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3) and [static-import-on-demand declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.4), which *are* top-level declarations, but not type declarations. Here, "static" refers to the names which are imported, not the import declarations themselves.
- The language is [statically typed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html), and expressions should have [statically known](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.5) types so that their safety is "statically guaranteed".
- The way that names, including field accesses, are bound at compile-time is referred to as [static resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3), or [static binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e24507).
- A lexical context can be a [static context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).
- The [invocation mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3) of a method invocation expression or method reference expression can be static.
- The class name used in one example implies that checked exceptions declared in a `throws` clause are [statically thrown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3).
- Part of the memory used by the JVM is referred to as [static storage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.2), and the same section refers to "static" linkage in the C programming language.
- The [preface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-0-preface8.html) to the JLS mentions static analysis tools.

There are no uses of the word "static" in the JLS to refer to top-level type declarations; so as well as not being explicitly static, they are not (and cannot be) "implicitly" static, by definition.

Comment: I searched about that topic recently ( Java SE 19 Specification) mention that (Page241) " The static modifier does not pertain to all nested classes. It pertains only to
member classes, whose declarations may use the static modifier, and not to local
classes or anonymous classes, whose declarations may not use the static modifier.However, some local classes are implicitly static, namely local
enum classes and local record classes, because all nested enum classes and nested
record classes are implicitly static"

Comment: I agree, it merely seems a language design choice. In C# static outer classes are not a problem, and the .NET framework enforces it even e.g. when using extension methods. But from a strict OOP paradigm point of view I can see why you would choose exclusively for outer instance classes in an OO language.

Answer (score 2):

`static` can be added nested classes of an interface, even though this is the default.

I believe `static` cannot be added to top level classes because initially there were no nested classes and you couldn't add static to any class.

Later nested class were added and static could be added to nested classes, however there is a tendency not to change the syntax any more than needed so it wasn't added to top level classes. (as there was no need/benefit)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we run a class JVM instantiates an object. JVM can create a number of objects, by definition Static means you have same set of copy to all objects.So, if top class is static then whenever you run a program it creates an Object and keeps over riding on to the same Memory Location.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate more on your answer, I think it will be better than the accepted one (I've upvoted).

Answer (score 0):

Will defining an outer class as static serve any other purposes other than a non-static class?

1. Every class is already common to all of its objects, and there is no need to make it static to become available to all of its objects.
2. We need a class name to access its static members because these members are part of a class while an outer class is part of a package. We can directly access the class by just writing package_name.class_name (similar to class_name.static_field_name). So again, there is no need to do something that's already there by default.
3. We do not need any object to access a class if it is visible. We can simply write package_name.class_name to access it. And by definition, a class is a blueprint for its objects, and we create a class to create objects from it (though an exception will always be there, like java.lang.Math). Again, there is no need to define an outer class as static.
   From the above points, we can say Java's creators had not allowed an outer class to be static because there is no need to make it static. Allowing to make the outer class static will only increase complications, ambiguity, and duplicity.

Refer this link for more details-
https://dzone.com/articles/why-an-outer-class-cant-be-static

Answer (score 0):

It would not make sense if a top-level class could be declared as static, it would imply that the class does not need to be instantiated and cannot have multiple objects. This contradicts the core concept of classes and objects in Java, where objects are created from classes to represent individual instances.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create something similar to the forbidden top-level static classes is to explicitly create a private constructor.

```
public final class Utils {
    private Utils() {
        // Static class
    }

    // An example common function that is missing from my Math library
    public static int abs(int v) {
        return 0 <= v ? v : -v;
    }
}
```

This class cannot be instantiated, like true static classes, and cannot have descendants. There is no way to change how my example common function works. I use it when I want to be sure that nobody will ever change the implementation of my function.

Answer (score -1):

Well I guess you dont understand properly if you desire to see a "static" keyword in an outer class.

In short how are you even going to use the feature of static on an outer class?

```
public class Outer
{
   public static int x = 0 ; 

}
```

Now you are going to do Outer.x to access the static variable . This would imply that x shares a single value across all objects of Outer.

Now that we have that away , of what consequence would the static keyword in the Outer class be ? .

Answer (score -1):

We can't declare outer (top level) class as static because the static keyword is meant for providing memory and executing logic without creating Objects, a class does not have a value logic directly, so the static keyword is not allowed for outer class.

Answer (score -2):

The access modifier supported for top level are class are as follows :

1) public

2) default

3) abstract

4) final

5) strictfp.

**Reason: Top level class**

Because the static keyword is meant for providing memory and executing logic without creating Objects, a class does not have a value logic directly, so the static keyword is not allowed for outer class and mainly as mentioned above static can't be used at Package level. It only used within the Class level.

Comment: I don't think the `default` applies for Java 11. I'm getting a `error: modifier default not allowed here` for `public default class StackOverflowTest {...}` Could you specify the Java version where this is allowed?

Answer (score -3):

1. Whenever we run a class JVM will create a object. All static objects are created in 
   static memory and not in heap memory. Meaning, we have same set of copy to all objects. 
   So if the top class is static and u run the pgm, it creates a static object and keep over 
   riding on to the same static memory. which is wrong.

2.We should define members as static which
  Should be common to all objects of the class.
  Since, Every class is already common to all of its objects and there is no need to make 
  it static to become available to all of its objects.