# Extending DialogFragment for a date picker

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker

This is the code that they provide, so I created a new class. But I'm getting errors in my new class. I'm getting an error when I'm defining `public static class DatePickerFragment`. The error is `Illegal modifier for the class DatePickerFragment; only public, abstract & final are permitted`

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full code. is this in Activity or in a separate .java file?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You have an illegal modifier. In particular, the "static" keyword is causing the error.

Comment: This is in a separate .java file which I thought the tutorial was doing.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have the code in a separate .java file. Get rid of `static` keyword.

If its a inner class then you can have static modifier say within the Activity class.

Also check this which says top level classes cannot be static

[Illegal modifier error for static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831791/illegal-modifier-error-for-static-class)

You can find an example @

[How to transfer the formatted date string from my DatePickerFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211684/how-to-transfer-the-formatted-date-string-from-my-datepickerfragment)

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware that the code was meant to be put inside of the activity.

Comment: @EGHDK There is no need to put the same inside Activity. Just get rid of static keyword

Comment: What would be the best way to get the int year, day, month passed back into my activity?

Comment: @EGHDK using interface a a call back to the activity. you can check this example i posted long time back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211684/how-to-transfer-the-formatted-date-string-from-my-datepickerfragment