# Implementing a generic container for a list of interface instances in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-8

Java 8 here. I have the following POJOs:

```
public interface HasPartNumber {
  String getPartNumber();
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class InventoryItem implements HasPartNumber {
  private String modelNumber;
  private String description;
  // lots of other fields here

  @Override
  public String getPartNumber() {
    return this.modelNumber;
  }
}

public class Inventory extends ArrayList<InventoryItem> {
  // Inventory is just an alias of a list of InventoryItem
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class PriceItem implements HasPartNumber {
  private String equipmentNumber;
  // lots of other fields here

  @Override
  public String getPartNumber() {
    return this.equipmentNumber;
  }
}

public class PriceRoster extends ArrayList<PriceItem> {
  // PriceRoster is just an alias of a list of PriceItem
}
```

I *understand* some of you may have an aversion to how I'm modeling `Inventory` and `PriceRoster`, but using the is-a and has-a golden rule, it is correct. An "inventory" is no more and no less than just a list of `InventoryItems`. Ditto for `PriceRoster`. And, the [Domain-Driven Design](https://dddcommunity.org/learning-ddd/what_is_ddd/) community would probably agree that these are valid data models if it makes sense to a developer reading the code.

*However*, I am not **married** to this design. And so while my druthers would be to keep this data model above, if it truly is *impossible* to accomplish what I describe below without changing the data model, I'll be flexible.

---

I am trying to write a generic `PartProcessor` class that will iterate through lists of `HasPartNumber` impls and perform processing on them. My best attempt:

```
public class PartProcessor<PART_CONTAINER extends List<HasPartNumber>> {

  public void process(PART_CONTAINER partContainer) {

    partContainer.stream().forEach(part -> {

      // Do something here

    });

  }

}
```

produces compilation errors when I go to instantiate the `PartProcessor`:

```
PartProcessor<Inventory> inventory = new PartProcessor<Inventory>();
```

The compiler errors I'm seeing are:

> "*Type parameter 'com.example.myapp.Inventory' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.util.List<com.example.myapp.HasPartNumber>'*"

Any ideas what I can do to get my `PartProcessor` working generically on any list of `HasPartNumbers` impl, including `Inventory` and `PriceRoster`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*bounded types makes the type covariant*:

```
 public class PartProcessor<PART_CONTAINER extends List<? extends HasPartNumber>> {...
```

For a broader read see [this answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902219/nested-wildcards/58631449#58631449).

Comment: Thanks @Eugene (+1) but can I place `PartProcessor` in its own source file (`PartProcessor.java`)? Doing so produces the compiler error: "_Modifier 'static' not allowed here_"...

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup of course you can, I can't guess though what exactly is not working for you.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11831828/5235665) you can't have a top-level static class

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup ah! right, a _top level_ class - no; but you don't need it as such, right?

Comment: I mean, I'd *prefer* to make it a top level class...where else would I put it?! Its generic to all lists of `HasPartNumbers`. So to me it doesn't make sense to put it inside of `Inventory.java` or `PriceRoster.java`. And `HasPartNumber` is just a one-method interface...so putting it inside of there seems weird to me as well!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup that is correct, it does not make sense, so put it as a top level class?

Comment: Haha I'm getting *really* confused now. Maybe I don't understand what is meant by a top-level class. To me, that means the outermost and only `class` defined inside a JAVA (.java) source file. If I'm wrong about that, please correct me. If I'm correct, then I'm not sure what you're telling me to do. Your solution (it seems) cannot be used for top-level classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202670/discussion-between-eugene-and-hotmeatballsoup).